# How can i fix the error when starting cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

it's my first time using Cassandra and when I try to run "CQLSH" command I get error like this.

```
C:\Users\RanggaSaputra>cqlsh
  File "C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.14\bin\cqlsh.py", line 146
    except ImportError, e:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

my device is windows 11

I've tried following the advice from YouTube trying to change the start_rpc and enable_user variables to true.

Answer (score 1):

What version of python do you use? I believe you'll want version 2.7 for Cassandra 3.11 as specified here:
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html
Not having the proper version is likely the issue.

Comment: My Python version is 3.10.7. So do i have download python version 2.7 ?

Comment: Yes, for Cassandra 3.11 you'll have to downgrade to Python 2.7, it doesn't support Python 3.  I believe you'd have to move to Cassandra 4 to get Python 3 supported.